# Numpy: how to compute this product between two arrays with different shapes?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

I am sorry that the title of my question may sound vague, since I do not know the exact name of such operation.

Given a tensor `A` (N×M×M) and a one-dimension array `b` (N), I would like to get another tensor `B` (N×M×M) such that each item (M×M) in `B` is the multiplication between `A` and `b`.

A possible but ugly solution is to flatten(reshape) `A` firstly, i.e, converting `A` into a 2D array, then apply a `dot` operation, and finally reshape back.

Is there any standard/simple operation in `numpy` to achieve this?

For example,

```
A = np.ones(12).reshape(3, 2, 2)
b = np.array([2, 3, 4])
```

The expected `B` is

```
[[[2, 2],
  [2, 2]],
 [[3, 3],
  [3, 3]],
 [[4, 4],
  [4, 4]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html); in two words, reshape your array `b` with the value `1` in some dimensions in order to get more control on what will happen; the total number of elements in `b` will remain unchanged but you may choose how the array will behave during the arithmetic operation:

```
A*b.reshape((3,1,1))
```

Comment: Can I use more elegant function, like `expand_dims`, rather than `reshape` for `b`?

Comment: As `b` is one dimension, we can write `b[:, np.newaxis][:, np.newaxis]`. Can we make it simpler?

Comment: @chenzhongpu What is wrong with the `reshape` method? You can have a look at `np.atleast_2d` and `np.atleast_3d` but I am not sure you will get anything simpler.

Comment: Anything that adds 2 new trailing dimensions will do.  The goal is an array with shape (3,1,1).